# ReactJS websocket results get translated by i18n

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, websocket

I have a ReactJS webapp where I use webscokets to retrieve ticker prices from an API. When my webapp is standalone it works perfectly you can see in the image below.

[image: 1]

But when I try to merge it in to my main react web app which has i18n localization no matter what I do I get this result. It seems it get stuck in the array or something. Maybe anyone has a clue how could I tackle this problem?
[image: 2]

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Loading from '../elements/Loading'
import Ticker from './Ticker'
import TradeHistory from './TradeHistory'
import OrderBook from './OrderBook'

class Trade extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false
        };
        this.tradesCount = 20;
        this.streams = ['@ticker','@depth20','@trade'];
    }

    _connectSocketStreams(streams) {
        streams = streams.join('/');
        let connection = btoa(streams);
        this[connection] = new WebSocket(`wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=${streams}`);
        this[connection].onmessage = evt => {
            let eventData = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            if(eventData.stream.endsWith('@ticker')){
                eventData.data.lastc = this.state.ticker ? this.state.ticker.c : 0
                this.props.dispatch({
                    type: 'SET_TICKER',
                    data: eventData.data
                })
                this.setState({
                    loadedTicker: true
                })
            }
            if(eventData.stream.endsWith('@trade')){
                if(this.props.trades && Object.keys(this.props.trades).length > 0){
                    let trades = this.props.trades;
                    trades.push(eventData.data);
                    trades = trades.slice(-1*this.tradesCount);
                    this.props.dispatch({
                        type: 'SET_TRADES',
                        data: trades
                    })
                    this.setState({
                        loadedTrades: true
                    })
                }
            }
            if(eventData.stream.endsWith('@depth20')){
                this.props.dispatch({
                    type: 'SET_DEPTH',
                    data: eventData.data
                })
                this.setState({
                    loadedDepth: true
                })
            }
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true
            })
        };
        this[connection].onerror = evt => {
            console.error(evt);
        }
    }

    _disconnectSocketStreams(streams){
        streams = streams.join('/');
        let connection = btoa(streams);
        if (this[connection].readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            this[connection].close();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        let symbol = this.props.match.params.symbol.toLowerCase();
        this._connectSocketStreams(this.streams.map(i => `${symbol}${i}`));

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.binance.com/api/v1/aggTrades?limit=${this.tradesCount}&symbol=${this.props.match.params.symbol}`
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.props.dispatch({
                type: 'SET_TRADES',
                data: response.data
            })
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                loadedTrades: true
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: false,
                error: error
            })
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        let symbol = this.props.match.params.symbol.toLowerCase();
        this._disconnectSocketStreams(this.streams.map(i => `${symbol}${i}`))
    }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, loadedDepth, loadedTicker, loadedTrades } = this.state;
        if (error) {
          return <div className="alert alert-danger">{error.message}</div>;
        }
        if (!isLoaded) {
          return <Loading />;
        }
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">{loadedTicker ? <Ticker {...this.props.ticker} /> : <Loading />}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-6">{loadedTrades ? <TradeHistory trades={this.props.trades}/> : <Loading />}</div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
      )
    }

}

export default connect(
    state => state
)(Trade)
```

Comment: please share us some code on how you integrated with your existing app

Comment: @OriPrice poster my ticker class I also have a few more reducer and so on. Just that it is working perfectly when it is stand alone but as soon as I merge it does not work any more.

Comment: probably you have some i18n HOC over your component that translate you props somehow

Comment: @OriPrice is there a way to prohibit translations of certain components?

Comment: first, we need to find out how its getting translated. it shouldn't be translated automatically. could you share the way you consume Ticker component?

Comment: @OriPrice I added the index.js file

Comment: it seems that it has nothing to do with i18n... try log the `...this.props.ticker` and see if you get what you expect

Comment: @OriPrice I receive undefined if I log only this.props.ticker but I i log ...this.props.ticker it crashes.

Comment: you cannot use spread on undefined. so this is your problem. your ticker prop is undefined.

Comment: @OriPrice just I have identical code running on my other web app and it is running well.

Comment: @OriPrice and my standalone app return an object on console.log

Comment: obviously, something is different between both deployments. its hard to help you without having the ability to compare them.

Comment: @OriPrice anyways thanks for your time I will take a look and try the implementation from scratch. Maybe I have missed something.